# Gulp-compass - cannot load sass-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sas, gulp, compass

After I updated sass and compass, I started seeing this issue when I run gulp-compass

```
LoadError on line ["247"] of/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb: cannot load such file -- sass-rails
```

I tried the following:

```
gem uninstall sass
gem uninstall compass
gem install sass
gem install compass --pre
```

However, I still see the same issue. It would be great if anyone could help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There was a dependency conflict.

This is what I did.

```
gem unisntall sass
gem unisntall compass 
gem uninstall compass-rails
gem uninstall sass-rails
```

and then

```
`gem install compass`
```